# How to loop audio from one second to another

Tags: java, android

I'm making an application with sounds that I want to loop.

The problem is that audios have a kind of fade in and fade out that every time it is played with mediaPlayer.setLooping(true); they make the loop sound very bad, because you hear it perfectly when it ends and when it starts again.

I would like to be able to play those audios from one particular second to another, for example to be able to loop from the second 00:00:04 to the second 00:00:14 and thus not hear the fade in and fade out.

At the moment I'm using this code to play the audios. Then in the button, I make the call that you see next

```
    public void playAudio(int audioId)
    {
        // stop the previous playing audio
        if(mMediaPlayer != null && mMediaPlayer.isPlaying())
        {
            mMediaPlayer.stop();
            mMediaPlayer.release();
            mMediaPlayer = null;
        }

        mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, audioId);

        mMediaPlayer.start();
        mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);

    }

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) { 

            playAudio(R.raw.sound1);

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a method called `startPosition(int initialTime)` which will seek `mediaPlayer` position before start() method

```
private void startPosition(int initialTime){
    mMediaPlayer.seekTo(initialTime);    //time in millisecond, e.g 4sec = 4000
}
```

call this method before `mMediaPlayer.start()` method.

Now create a thread which will run endlessly and seek your mediaplayer position back to initial on upper limit reached.
**Edit**
Replace your playAudio() method with the below and change `upperTimerLimit` with specific value e.g 14000 (14 second).

```
public void playAudio(int audioId)
{
    // stop the previous playing audio
    if(mMediaPlayer != null && mMediaPlayer.isPlaying())
    {
        mMediaPlayer.stop();
        mMediaPlayer.release();
        mMediaPlayer = null;
    }

    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, audioId);

    mMediaPlayer.start();
    new Thread(new Runnable() { 
        public void run(){        
            while(true){
                if(mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()-UpperTimeLimit >=0){ //UpperTimeLimit should be in milliseconds. UpperTimerLimit is the specific second after which player should start again the sound.
                    startPosition(initialTime);    //Call the startPosition(int initialTime)
                }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

> Create the thread right after `mMediaPlayer.start()`
>   There is no need of `mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);` in your playAudio() method.

Hope this will work.

Comment: Can you put the thread code more clearly? Thank you in advance :)

Comment: It works great! Thank you very much, you made my day :D

Comment: If it works then accept the answer so other user will get benifit